# Trying to dynamically set a property and a target field name for an obj variable

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have different fields where I type in player names.

I would like to create a loop that cycles through all fields and adds the properties to a certain object:

```
for (i = 0; i <= playersCount; i++) {
        var newTournament = {
            player + i: event.target.player + i.value
        }
    }
```

I tried with + and with [player + i].

How do update newTournament with the values picked up from the fields and consecutive property names?

Comment: `player + i: event.target.player + i.value` what kind of syntax is this? i've never seen anything like this, what is this suposed to do ?

Comment: well it makes no sense, it was just to give an idea of what I'd like to do: create different properties in an obj and have them take the value of consecutively named field names.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var newTournament = {};
for (i = 0; i <= playersCount; i++) {
    newTournament[player + i] = event.target.player + i.value;
}
```

Comment: for the key name it works, but for the field name it gives NaN.

Comment: Not sure what form the input data is, but you can try this way `event.target.player.toString() + i.value.toString();`

Comment: the input data is a string, I'm gonna give this a try, thanks.